# Storing TOTP codes on a Feiteian ePass FIDO key

Tags: one-time-password, fido

I'm looking for some Android apps that can store / read TOTP codes off of a Feitian ePass FIDO key using NFC.  There appears to be a fairly simple way with a yubico key / and key but I don't know how to do this with a Feitian.  What is the actual term for offloading these seeds to a physical key?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a way to program the device from an Android app and extract the seed (secret) from the key. I suspect you'll need to use the manufacturers app to do that.

Comment: I don't think he wants to extract the secret - he wants to read/generate the TOTP codes that are *based* on the secret.

Comment: There are several different Yubikey and Feitian products. Some yubikeys support this and some don't, I expect it will be the same for Feitian products. Regardless, this isn't related to FIDO, it's additional functionality.

Comment: If you scroll down to the product comparison table [here](https://www.ftsafe.com/products/FIDO/Single_Button_FIDO), I see some of their products support HOTP, but none support TOTP.

Comment: Feiteian ePass FIDO key does not have TOTP listed at all in the specs.